# $elemMatch returning false positive

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**my query:**

```
{ 'objects.item.opts1.opts2': { '$elemMatch': [ { name: 'false' } ] } }
```

**returns:** any item that has anything in the array opts2, even if I change 'name' to some field that is not present the result will always be the same

**mongoose schema:**

```
var MySchema = new Schema({
    objects: {
        item: {
            opts1: [{
                opts2: [{
                    name:   { type: String },
                }]
            }],      
        },
});
```

Comment: { 'objects.item.opts1.opts2': { '$elemMatch':  { name: 'false' } } }
try this without array in $elemMatch.

Comment: @ShreyanceJain Can you write that as the answer?

Comment: @chridam sure I just thought to write it in comment as it looks like a typo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use following wihout array in $elemMatch....

```
{ 'objects.item.opts1.opts2': { '$elemMatch': { name: 'false' } } }
```